# Unexpected results for "sizeof" of strings

Tags: c++, c, sizeof

Why would sizeof in the following cases print different values:

```
printf("%d",sizeof("ab")); //print 3

char* t="ab";
printf("%d",sizeof(t)); //print 4
```

In the first case I have 2 characters... Shouldn't `sizeof` print 2? Because they are 2 bytes?

Comment: The second one gives the size of the pointer. Let me try to confuse you, try `strlen` on `t` and see what it gives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Strings in C are null terminated.

"ab" in memory looks like `'a' 'b' '\0'`

While `t` is a pointer, so size is 4.

Comment: oo ic, then how can i get the actual sizeof t? not the pointer but the number of elements it has...

Comment: @scatman You can't. Use `std::string` and then at runtime you can get the size.

Comment: @scatman: you could use `strlen(t)` which would give you actual length of string.

Comment: @scatman for a generic array you can use sizeof(t)/sizeof(t[0]), but for strings stick with the strlen() function.

Comment: @Mark B. not true, granted std::string is safer and perfered for c++, strlen will return the length of the string (well how ever many characters until it encounters '\0'), and what I posted will return the number of elements in an array, provided the compiler has seen the array declaration.

Comment: @diverscuba `t` isn't an array so `sizeof(t)/sizeof(t[0])` is meaningless here.

Comment: @scatman "sizeof" specifically refers to the number of bytes occupied by a value -- it is not the number of elements of an array or collection; that would be referred to as "size" or "length". Here, `strlen("ab")` and `strlen(t)` both return `2`.

Answer (score 7):

`t` is a pointer to an array containing `"ab"`.  Its size is the size of a pointer.

`"ab"` is an array containing `"ab"`.  Its size is the size of that array, which is three characters because you have to account for the null terminator.

Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: +1 for "arrays are not pointers". I have had people argue with me about this even after I have quoted the language standard, Dennis Ritchie, and other authoritative sources. In a comment here, someone wrote "for a generic array you can use sizeof(t)/sizeof(t[0])" ... but that's completely meaningless since `t` is not an array!

Answer (score 3):

Because in the first case you are asking for the sizeof an array.  The second time you are asking for the size of a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

A string literal is a char array, not a char *.

```
char a[] = "ab";
char * t = a;
printf("%d",sizeof(a)); //print 3
printf("%d",sizeof(t)); //print 4
```

Answer (score 3):

The *type* of the string literal `"ab"` is `const char(&)[3]`.
So `sizeof("ab") = sizeof(const char(&)[3]) = sizeof(char) * 3` which is 3 on your machine.

And in the other case, `t` is just a pointer.
So `sizeof(t) = sizeof(void*)` which is 4 bytes on your machine.

--

**Note:**

If you prepend `"ab"` with `L`, and make it `L"ab"`, then,

The *type* of the string literal `L"ab"` is `const wchar_t(&)[3]`.
So `sizeof(L"ab") = sizeof(const wchar_t(&)[3]) = sizeof(wchar_t) * 3` which is 12 on ideone:

http://ideone.com/IT7aR

So that is because `sizeof(wchar_t) = 4` on ideone which is using GCC to compile!