# malloc and heap in c

Tags: c, pointers, heap-memory

consider the code below:

```
#include "list.h"
struct List
{
   int size;
   int* data;
};
List *list_create()
{
   List *list;
   printf("%d %d",sizeof(list),sizeof(List));
   list = malloc(sizeof(list));
   assert(list != NULL);
   if (list != NULL) {
      list->size = 0;
   }
   return list;
}
```

The number printed out is "4 8", i assume this is the 4 bytes taken by "int size" in List object?and the size of "int* data" is 0 cause nothing has assigned to data?
the size of int pointer is also 4 bytes so the type List take 8 bytes in total? or there are some thing else going on? Can some one help me understand all this in detail?

then the malloc() get 4 bytes from the heap and assign the address to the pointer list? later in main if i do "list->data[i]=1;" this will give me a run time error why? Is it because I cant change contents in the heap? but if i do "list->size++" this would work,
isn't the whole list object is in the heap?

really need some help here

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you `sizeof(struct List)`?

Comment: Your runtime error is because you haven't initialized the pointer to anything. You need to allocate space for it, too.

Comment: This is not valid C because you omitted the `struct` in `sizeof(List)`. Are you using a C++ compiler?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sizeof question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463325/sizeof-question)

Comment: sorry i have a head file #include "list.h" contains the typedef thing

Comment: `list_create()` should be `list_create(void)`.

Comment: @SalvatorePreviti: Even when you add the code `list->data[i] = 1` as noted in the post?

Comment: Even, sizeof is not related to what you are doing with variables. To allocate a variable length array you need to use again malloc.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan Why is the void necessary? I have never used it in all my coding and no warnings (even on pre c90).

Comment: @chacham15 In C, `(void)` means "this function has no arguments," while `()` means "this function accepts an unspecified argument list." They have different behaviours.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan What are the different behaviors? I haven't ever come across that difference before. Do you have a link?

Comment: @chacham15 I just told you what they are. For more info, see other SO questions such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032/is-there-a-difference-between-foovoid-and-foo-in-c-or-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sizeof(List*)` is the size of a pointer to a List struct.

`sizeof(list)` in your case, since variable list is of type `List*` is the same as `sizeof(List*)`.

`sizeof(List)` instead is the size of the struct List, it contains two 32 bit variables (I assume you are using a 32 bit compiler obviously), an integer and a pointer and your compiler decided that the right size for your struct is 8 bytes.

Pointers to types are usually 4 byte in 32 bit compilers and 8 bytes in 64 bit compilers.

As a side note, reading your code however i read you never initialize list->data, you should initialize it to something somewhere i guess.

This is C++ however, you should write

```
typedef struct { ... } List; // This is C.
```

Sizeof operator is evaluated at compile time, not at runtime, it gives only information of the size of a type.
You cannot, for example, know how much elements are in a dynamic array with sizeof, if you were trying to accomplish this, sizeof(pointer) will give you the size in byte of the pointer type.

As something to read about what is a pointer and what is an array i would suggest you to read http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html or http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm

Comment: ERROR: pointer size is determined by the compiler, not the system. It isnt a rare thing to have a 32 bit compilation on a 64 bit system meaning that sizeof(void*) = 4

Comment: You also forget that alignment affects the sizeof a struct

Comment: Packing too indeed, but it would be a little out of topic.

Comment: so if i wanna use data as an int array i should do "data=(int*)malloc(somenumber)"? and pointer type of int and int array are the same in syntax "int*"? i do got a run time error when i was trying use the variable data as a array

Answer (score 2):

Technically your code has an error in it.

The code should read: `sizeof(struct List)` or have `typedef struct List List;` somewhere.

But yes, `sizeof(list)` is the size of the variable list. Since list is a pointer it is equivalent to `sizeof(void*)` which on your system/compiler is 4.

`sizeof(struct List)` is the size of the struct which is `sizeof(int)`+`sizeof(int*)`+`any alignment issues`. The alignment thing is often forgotten but is very important as it can change the size of the struct in unexpected ways.